# Retrofit non-api method

Tags: android, retrofit

I'm using Retrofit for my Rest API operation. Now my interface have 2 methods, 1 for Rest API call that I have declared using Retrofit syntax as usual and another one is just do a simple calculation so it doesn't need to make any Rest API call, as the following (just a quick examples):

```
public interface ITripService
{
    int getPrice(LatLng start, LatLng end, String serviceType);
    @GET("driver/nearbydrivers")
    Call<List<NearbyDriver>> getNearbyDrivers(@Query("latitude")String latitude,
                                              @Query("longitude")String longitude,
                                              @Query("administrative_area_level_1")String administrative_area_level_1,
                                              @Query("administrative_area_level_2")String administrative_area_level_2,
                                              @Query("serviceType")String serviceType);
}
```

So now in my app I can call the Rest-method-version as follow:

```
ServiceFactory.getTripService().getNearbyDrivers(null, null, null, null, null).enqueue(new Callback<List<NearbyDriver>>()
                            {
                                @Override
                                public void onResponse(Call<List<NearbyDriver>> call, Response<List<NearbyDriver>> response)
                                {
                                    
                                }

                                @Override
                                public void onFailure(Call<List<NearbyDriver>> call, Throwable t)
                                {

                                }
                            });
```

Retrofit will do the rest for me, like network call, get API response,...

But with *getPrice* I need to do some custom operations inside. How can I do it?
Any ideal would be appreciate!

Comment: what you mean by custom operations??

Comment: @ALTegani I mean I don't need to make any Api call inside it. For example I just return some value. How can I do this, or is it has any syntax allow this custom implementation? Sorry I just discovered this library a few minutes ago. Thank you.

Comment: I suggest  make it method (in response side activity called getPrice())that you send it the data from onResponse and return you with the value you need??

Comment: if i got u correctly you retrieve data from server that u need to process for specific value ???

Comment: you want perform calculation after getting response of API

Comment: Not fully understand what you mean, but an example code here:
in my MainActivity: 
ServiceFactory.getTripService().getPrice(null,null,null); 
How can I do this without create any implementation class of ITripService?

Comment: you get this LatLng,LatLng,serviceType from server and you want to calculate price based on them??

Comment: Yes something like that. @ALTegani

Comment: in your activity make method called... int getprice(LatLng start, LatLng end, String serviceType) in onresponse method after you insure that data receved correctly pass the values to the method to perform the calculation...it will return int value which is the price

Comment: if you have problem to implement it...post the  json response

Comment: Is there any way that I can call getPrice independently and outside the onResponse without split it to another interface?

Comment: yes method block

Comment: What did you mean @AL?

Comment: i mean make method that calculate the price